# RedShift - array_position function

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Im trying to extract an array using `array_position` to return the position of a specific string. Unfortunately, redshift doesn't have this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I have created a python UDF.

```py
create or replace function array_position (anyarray varchar(65535),
anyelement varchar(65535))
returns varchar(65535)
stable as $$
    a_list = str(anyarray).split(',')
    find = anyelement
    indices = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(a_list):
        if value == find:
            indices.append(idx)
    return (str(indices))
$$ language plpythonu;
```

#### Code sample:

```sql
===>
select array_position('1,1,2,2,1','1');
 array_position
----------------
 [0, 1, 4]
(1 row)

===>
create temp table test (col varchar(100));
insert into test (col) values ('1,1,1,2,2,2,1');
select array_position(col,'1') from test;

 array_position
----------------
 [0, 1, 2, 6]
(1 row)
```

Hope, this will help someone to simulate the `array_position` function in RedShift.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to unroll / unnest / unpivot the array and apply a WHERE clause.   See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest

Using an UDF as you propose will function file for small number of rows but Redshift tables often have very large tables and UDF do not perform well on large row counts.  Calling a UDF millions of times just is too much overhead. So watch for scaling issues.